# How to store list values in to matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

```
set.seed(650)
library(maxLik)
y = c(rnorm(15,1,1), rnorm(15,3,1))
dat = data.frame(y)
B = 3 # number bootstrap sample
n = length(dat$y)
n1 = 15
boot.samples = matrix(sample(dat$y, size = B * n, replace = TRUE), n, B)
ml = list()
boot.l = 0
va.l = NULL
for (j in 1:B) {
  boot.l = boot.samples[, j]
  for (i in 1:n) {
    LLl <- function(param) {
      mul <- param[1]
      sigmal <- param[2]
      sum(log(dnorm(dat[1:i, ], mul, sigmal)))
    }
    ml[[i]] = coef(maxLik(logLik = LLl, start = c(mul = 1, sigmal = 1)))
  }
  va.l = matrix(unlist(ml), n-1, B*2, byrow = TRUE)
}
va.l
```

The following are my output

[image]
However, when I print the list I have the following output.
[image]

My question is how can I have mul estimates for j=1 in the 1st column,  sigmal estimates for j = 1 in the second column and mul estimates for j=2 in the 3rd column,  sigmal estimates for j = 2 in the 4th column and so on?

Are there any other way do this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code does not run: `could not find function "maxLik"`. Could you add the needed package or rewrite to be independent of that function?

Comment: From `library(maxLik)`

Comment: Why do you need a list? your matrix `va.l` seems to do just fine.

Comment: @Frank For example, in the second picture those estimated values are from the sample `j = 1`. If you look at the first picture they are stored by columns. I want to have, for `j=1`, all `mul` values in the first column and all `sigaml` values in the second column. Further, for `j = 2`, all all `mul` values in the third column and all `sigaml` values in the fourth column and so on.